# LMAX Disruptor as a blocking queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, garbage-collection, disruptor-pattern

Is there any way i can have both in one structure -

1. Semantics of BlockingQueue, ie - non blocking peek, blocking poll and blocking put. Multiple providers one consumer.
2. RingBuffer, which effectively works as an object pool, so instead of putting new object in ring buffer, i want to reuse existing object there, copying the state. So basically the functionality LMAX disruptor has out of the box.

Is there something which works like that already?
I guess i can try and use Disruptor for that, i already can use it as a blocking queue with blocking put(if the ring buffer is "full") if i understand correctly. It already has the "reusable objects" semantics i need. So the only problem is how to create a client which would be able to PULL objects(instead of using callbacks), so as i'm not really familiar with internal Disruptor structure - can it be done? With all those sequencers, creating a new EventProcessor or something like that?

And no, the obvious solution of having a blocking queue on a client side and getting from it is not an ideal solution, as it breaks the whole point of using the disruptor object pool - you'll need to have a new pool now, or just create a new objects in the callback before putting in that blocking queue etc, and i don't want to have any garbage created at all.

So is there a way to achieve it with Disruptor, or any other performance oriented/garbage free java library?

Comment: Why do you have a need for blocking operations?  Note: you have to be careful how you reusing objects in a pool to ensure a) you never recycle an object in use and b) it's not slower than creating new objects.

Comment: Consumption will be slower than putting objects in the queue, that's the point - if the consumer isn't ready to consume the new event yet(at his own pace) all pushers need to be blocked. Not sure i understood point a, sorry. And i need blocking operations because i need blocking queue, there's a lot of valid reasons for seeking semantics of blocking queue. The only thing the blocking queue isn't giving me - i can't reuse objects in the blocking queue obviously, i need to create new objects(or use external object pool).

Comment: "i need blocking operations because i need blocking queue" I assume you have thought about the that using a blocking operation is slower and will seriously impact your latency but it doesn't matter for your use case so I would use a queue which performs a blocking operation.

Comment: In short, developers use models like Distributor because they need to *avoid* blocking operations and busy waiting is most likely the only solution.  If you need a blocking operation you have a fundamentally different use case.

Comment: Well, i just need to consume at my own pace and i need to block pushers if the queue is full, that's all. Sure it's slower than not doing that, but there's no way around that sadly. But at least it surely can be done without creating additional garbage at least, right? So the first solution i thought is to have a regular BlockingQueue and have a separate plain RingBuffer of the same size, so every push to the queue will take a next object from the RingBuffer(copying the data to it, of course). But it seems wasteful, besides you need to be careful with multithreading.

Comment: I understand, it just the functionality Disruptor provides ALMOST fits in what i need, it's of course created for a different case, but my requirements are LESS restrictive - i WANT blocking operations instead of avoiding them. So it looks like i can just create that blocking "pulling" client by the custom EventProcessor. But i'm happy to use something else if it suits better.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need them to block instead of busy waiting? "But it seems wasteful" In latency sensitive applications blocking is more expensive than busy waiting.

Comment: Pushers are already blocked(unless i misunderstand it) when the ring buffer is full, so that suits me. And the reason i want to PULL from the queue is the fact that one thread needs to check multiple ring buffers, by design.

Comment: In which case I would use a non-blocking operation and poll all the ring buffers in the same thread (or in a few threads)

Comment: BTW I work on a different solution, http://chronicle.software/products/chronicle-queue/ but it uses a similar non blocking strategy for the same reasons. I have seen it work successfully in reducing latencies.

Comment: Exactly, the "consumer" thread which checks for multiple ring buffers, need to be able to go through all of them and check if there's something there or not. And he can't do it now because he can't PEEK/POLL stuff from the ring buffer(unless i'm dumb, which can be the case), he can only subscribe for events, which is obviously not great idea if you want to check multiple ring buffers. That's the whole problem, i guess. So it looks like i just need to dive in it and figure out the way to do peek/poll? I'm not against busy looping through all of them to be honest, if that's the only way.

Comment: I'm aware of Chronicle products, thanks Peter :) they seem great!

Comment: So my confusion is likely to be a lack of understanding the difference in Disruptor.  Chronicle Queue doesn't use callbacks (though it supports them) and polling any number of queues is trivial/exposed to the develop as something they have to worry about.  Note: it works differently in that it persists every message so it' not a drop in replacement, nor intended to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For curious, i haven't been able to get a "blocking pull" semantics from the Disruptor itself, but of course it's trivial to add "blocking" functionality to the non-blocking pull. "Peek" functionality by itself is possible but not efficient(you need to copy the item again and again on each peek) and can be replaced by just caching the results of "poll".

So, the minimal raw solution, implemented only the methods i need:

```
public class DisruptorMPSCQueue<T extends ICopyable<T>> {

    private final RingBuffer<T> ringBuffer;
    private final EventPoller<T> eventPoller;
    private T tempPolledEvent;

    private EventPoller.Handler<T> pollerHandler = new EventPoller.Handler<T>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEvent(final T event, final long sequence, final boolean endOfBatch) throws Exception {
            tempPolledEvent.copyFrom(event);
            return false;
        }
    };

    public DisruptorMPSCQueue(EventFactory<T> typeConstructor, int size) {
        ringBuffer = RingBuffer.createMultiProducer(typeConstructor, size);
        eventPoller = ringBuffer.newPoller();
        ringBuffer.addGatingSequences(eventPoller.getSequence());
    }

    /**
     * Blocking, can be called from any thread, the event will be copied to the ringBuffer
     */
    public void put(final T event) {
        long sequence = ringBuffer.next(); // blocked by ringBuffer's gatingSequence
        ringBuffer.get(sequence).copyFrom(event);
        ringBuffer.publish(sequence);
    }

    /**
     * Not blocking, can be called from any thread, the event will be copied to the ringBuffer
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the element cannot be added at this time due to capacity restrictions
     */
    public void offer(final T event) {
        long sequence;
        try {
            sequence = ringBuffer.tryNext();
        } catch (InsufficientCapacityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e); // to mimic blockingQueue
        }
        ringBuffer.get(sequence).copyFrom(event);
        ringBuffer.publish(sequence);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve top of the queue(removes from the queue). NOT thread-safe, can be called from one thread only.
     *
     * @param destination top of the queue will be copied to destination
     * @return destination object or null if the queue is empty
     */
    public T poll(final T destination) {
        try {
            tempPolledEvent = destination;  // yea, the poller usage is a bit dumb
            EventPoller.PollState poll = eventPoller.poll(pollerHandler);
            if (poll == EventPoller.PollState.PROCESSING) {
                return tempPolledEvent;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

We open sourced Conversant Diruptor which includes DiruptorBlockingQueue earlier this year.   You can find the code on [github](https://github.com/conversant/disruptor)

Conversant Disruptor is trivial to include in almost any project because it supports the BlockingQueue api and is published on Maven Central.

Comment: Thanks a lot John, i'll definitely check it out! Are there any benchmarks/articles available about it?

Comment: Yes, there is a [disruptor benchmark](https://github.com/conversant/disruptor_benchmark).   In my measurement Conversant Disruptor is 2x faster than MPMC and LMAX at least 5x better than anything in the JDK.   I'd love to hear what you find in your own app.   There is also a half decent [wiki](https://github.com/conversant/disruptor/wiki).   I recently gave a talk discussing Java concurrency and Disruptor, find it on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/jVMOgQgYzWU).